# Sqalchemy slow async execute

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have an async FastApi service running on kustomizse behind nginx and a NLB. Been working all good but doing some profiling locally I noticed the db query I have using sqlalchemy asyncSessions() and AsyncEngine seems to be a bit of a bottleneck, but I can not see much online and the way I have it set up I think is okay.

The query is as the below:

```py
    async with AsyncSession(master_db) as session:
        result = (
            await session.execute(
                select(User, UserMapping, UserOrders, UserInvoices)
                .join(UserMapping, User.id == UserMapping.user_id)
                .outerjoin(
                    UserOrders,
                    and_(User.email == UserOrders.email),
                )
                .outerjoin(
                    UserInvoices,
                    and_(
                        UserInvoices.email == User.email,
                        UserInvoices.state == "paid",
                    ),
                )
                .where(UserMapping.uuid == uuid)
                .order_by(UserOrders.created_at.desc())
                .limit(3)
            )
        ).all()
```

and as for the engine, I create it like so:

```py
@functools.cache
def get_master_db(settings: Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    master_db_engine: AsyncEngine = create_async_engine(
        settings.master_db_url,
        pool_recycle=3600,
        pool_pre_ping=True
    )
    return master_db_engine
```

which is set as a dependency in my fastapi like so:

```py
async def get_user_orders_and_invoices(
    user_uuid: int,
    master_db_engine: AsyncEngine = Depends(get_master_db):
   # make call to the method which has the above sqlalchemy call
   await get_user_order_and_invoices(master_db_engine,user_uuid)
```

As far from profiling using by pyinstrument the .execute() seems to sometimes take a while.

To tick some stuff I know people will mention:

- The query is exactly what I need
- Yes there are indexes on the right fields
- The query in raw SQL if I hit directly in MySQL cli is takes a minimal amount of time
- The schema of the tables can not change as they are legacy and is not possible at this time

The bottleneck is 100% at sqlalchemy level or at least at my Python code level. If there is any help that would be great thank you!

for reference:

- using python 3.11
- latest fastapi
- aiomysql
- sqalchemy 1.4

Comment: Have you tried testing your raw SQL query using just `aiomysql` with code something like [this](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/b79329b32bc27c4ebb44400f05be7ffb)?

Comment: @GordThompson just did there and the time log prints retrieved in 0.2 seconds - will try it full e2e with that

Comment: Did you verify that the query is the same on both sides by setting `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO`?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes they query is as expected - only SLIGHT difference it it’s a left outer join instead of a left join but other than that it is executing the exact same query

Comment: Left join and left outer join are the same in MySQL, so that shouldn't be the issue. How much data is this query returning, including all relations and everything? Sometimes what takes time in SQLAlchemy is constructing the Python objects from the returned data.

Comment: @M.O. it’s only ever returning a max of 3 rows with each row having 23 columns - all of which are only small data types (str or int) so nothing I would imagine being CRAZY right?

Comment: No, that's not gonna be the issue then.

Comment: This could do with more information to be properly answerable. What is the structure of the tables? How much data do they contain? How are you currently taking your measurements? What is the current query time?  Without this kind of detail people can only guess at what the problem might be.

Answer (score -1):

try to create session like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine, AsyncEngine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import select, and_
import functools

###; Engine creation with caching and potential performance tuning parameters

@functools.cache
def get_master_db(db_url):
    master_db_engine: AsyncEngine = create_async_engine(
        db_url,
        echo=False,  # Turn off echo to reduce logging overhead
        pool_recycle=3600,
        pool_pre_ping=True,
        pool_size=10,  # Adjust pool size to your needs
        max_overflow=20  # Adjust max overflow to your needs
    )
    return master_db_engine

##; AsyncSession factory creation
##; Avoids automatic refresh of instances upon commit
AsyncSessionFactory = sessionmaker(
    bind=get_master_db(),
    class_=AsyncSession,
    expire_on_commit=False  
)
```

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem?

Comment: Not "solve", just "improve"。 There is no solution for "performance", only  improvement for every OP steps. Most "db-performance-bottleneck" is caused by composed-db-query, which is depends on biz-logic.

Answer (score -2):

Overall, these optimizations can help improve the performance of your SQLAlchemy async query by reducing the amount of data processed and the number of database queries executed. This version of the query utilizes a subquery to fetch the top 3 orders for each user, avoiding unnecessary joins and outer joins.

```
from sqlalchemy import subquery

async with AsyncSession(master_db) as session:
    orders_subquery = (
        select(UserOrders)
        .filter(UserOrders.email == User.email)
        .order_by(UserOrders.created_at.desc())
        .limit(3)
    )

    result = (
        await session.execute(
            select(User, UserMapping)
            .join(UserMapping, User.id == UserMapping.user_id)
            .options(selectinload(User.orders), selectinload(User.invoices))
            .where(UserMapping.uuid == uuid)
            .filter(User.email.in_(select([UserOrders.email]).select_from(orders_subquery)))
        )
    ).all()
```

This query utilizes selectinload to selectively load related entities (User.orders and User.invoices). This helps in reducing the number of database queries required to fetch related data, resulting in improved performance.